# How can I show a table with the sum of value x of all childeren within Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm have an elasticsearch database with documents stored the following way(, seperates the documents):

```
{
  "path":"path/to/data"
  "kind": "type1"
},
{
  "path":"path/to/data/values1"
  "kind": "type2"
  "x": 2
},
{
  "path":"path/to/data/values2"
  "kind": "type2"
  "x": 2
},
{
  "path":"path/to/data/datasub"
  "kind": "type1"
},
{
  "path":"path/to/data/datasub/values1"
  "kind": "type2"
  "x": 1
}
```

Now I want the create table view/chart show all type2's with all the sum of x of all their childeren.

So I expect the total of path/to/data to be 5 and the total of path/to/data/datasub 1.

To consider: the depth of this structure could theoretically be unlimited

I'm running Elastichsearch 7 and Kibana 7 and I want to use the table visualisation  to start with but I would like to be able to use this kind of aggregation throughout multiple visualisations. I have Googles a lot and found all kinds of Elastichsearch queries but nothing on how to achieve this in Kibana.

All help is much appreciated

Comment: can you show us how the output should look like?

Comment: Yes. It is simular to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819234/elasticsearch-using-the-path-hierarchy-tokenizer-to-access-different-level-of.

I got that working now for my path field. But now I can't seem to filter on my path anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who run into the same question:

The solution I ended up using is to split the path in to tokens prior to importing it into Elasticsearch. So consider a document having a path like "/this/is/a/path". This becomes the following array in the document:

```
[
  "/this",
  "/this/is",
  "/this/is/a",
  "/this/is/a/path"
]
```

You can then use a terms aggregation on it with various metrics to calculate your desired measurements.